# Is it worth upgrading Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04?

Tags: versions

A few years ago, I used Ubuntu 10.04, and i liked it a lot. It never crashed. Then I have to change to Win*** because of work.

But this year, I heard about Ubuntu 12.04 and I wanted to install it. I've done this, but I have a lot of crashes. I don't do something special to make ubuntu crash, but sometimes it shows me a crash message.

So, is it worth migrating to 12.04? Do somebody stay with the 10.04? I really want to use ubuntu, and I will, but I don't know if it worth to use the newest release or with the 10.04.

If i install the 10.04 version, ubuntu tells me all the time to upgrade to the new version? Or will I use it fine?

What do you suggest me?

Thanks everybody for your time, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here, thanks!

Comment: If Ubuntu is crashing, that's a bug, probably due to a driver. You should [follow the procedure for bug reports](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Be prepared to give as much information as possible on your hardware and on what happens when the system crashes (including full messages).

Comment: @Gilles: by "crash messages" he probably means the Apport error-reporting stuff, not the fatal kind of crash ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ubuntu 10.04 until April 2013. There will always be bugs early on after release, so many will prefer to wait a while before upgrading. When Apport (crash message) appears, that doesn't mean there's a serious error. It simply enables you to easily file bugs so that issues can be fixed. Most of the time, these messages doesn't really cause any problems.

There are benefits from using 12.04, such as the new Unity shell which is very nice when you get to know it. But there's nothing wrong with sticking with 10.04 and upgrade when you feel comfortable with it. It will not nag about upgrades. When there are updates for 10.04, you'll get a button that you can click to upgrade to 12.04 instead, but that's entirely optional and it's the same dialog that would appear in any case, so it's not disturbing.